# Filter the rows in a list of tuples using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I am looking for a quicker way to filter out the list of tuples, using numpy and avoiding loops.

```
A = [(27157, 4),
       (24814, 0),
       (1047, 2),
       (18265, 2),
       (2857, 4),
       (23854, 2),
       (36881, 0)]
```

Now I have to filter it based on the second element, i.e. 4.
If '4' is present form one list 'B', if not form list 'C'.

That is:

```
B = [(27157, 4),(2857, 4)]
C = [(24814, 0),(1047, 2),(18265, 2),(23854, 2),(36881, 0)]
```

Comment: If it really is a list (not already an array), a list operation probably will be fastest.  There's a significant overhead when creating an array from a list.

Comment: Yes, currently its the list of tuples, on which I am performing the operation using for loop, but I am looking out for a quicker method, so thought of using numpy.

Comment: The kind of thing you are trying to isn't particularly fast, even if you start  with an array.  But do your own time tests,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With NumPy, you can use Boolean indexing to return arrays:

```
mask = A[:, 1] == 4
B = A[mask]
C = A[~mask]
```

This requires your input to be a NumPy array:

```
A = np.array([(27157, 4),
              (24814, 0),
              (1047, 2),
              (18265, 2),
              (2857, 4),
              (23854, 2),
              (36881, 0)])
```

Answer (score 0):

To be fast you must turn you list of tuple in a more efficient data structure. if you want to keep tuples, you can use a structured array :

```
dt=dtype([('val',int),('key',int)])
B=ndarray(len(A),dt,array(A))

B[B['key']==4] #--> array([(27157, 4), ( 2857, 4)],...
B[B['key']!=4] #--> array([(24814, 0), ( 1047, 2), (18265, 2), (23854, 2), (36881, 0)],...
```